# Unexpected behavior of filter inside a function dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that filters a `data.frame` based on the unique values of a group column that is passed to the function

```
la <- function(df, grp){
  gr <- df %>% pull({{grp}}) %>% unique()
  purrr::map(gr, function(x){
    print(x)
    filter(df, {{grp}} == x)
  })
}
```

When I use it with this df,

```
x <- structure(list(mac = c("dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", "dc:a6:32:2d:8c:ca", 
"dc:a6:32:2d:b8:62", "dc:a6:32:2d:ca:3f"), datetime = structure(c(1594644546, 
1594645457, 1594645375, 1594645080), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Comment = c("FED2", "FED7", "FED1", "FED6")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

```
la(x, mac)
```

I get the proper prints and the subsets.
However, when I use it with this other df, which should be equivalent, it doesn't work as expected.

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1594644600, 1594644900, 
1594645200, 1594645500, 1594645800, 1594646100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), movement = c(9940.50454596681, 10779.7747307276, 
7148.52826988968, 7687.54314683339, 8797.06954533588, 7524.02474093548
), x = c(606, NA, 240, NA, 504, NA), y = c(386, NA, 274, NA, 
56, NA), i_x = c(606, 228, 214, 407.5, 500, 292.947368421053), 
    i_y = c(386, 286, 258, 49.1666666666667, 56, 234), mac = c("dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", 
    "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", 
    "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b", "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b")), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(filename = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), datetime = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector")), movement = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), y = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), i_x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), i_y = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = "\t"), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I get 0 rows on each type of group (my real example has the same groups as the ones for the `x` dataframe).
Interestingly, this works as expected.

```
la(select(head(df), mac, datetime), mac)
[1] "dc:a6:32:21:59:2b"
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  mac               datetime           
  <chr>             <dttm>             
1 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 12:50:00
2 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 12:55:00
3 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 13:00:00
4 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 13:05:00
5 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 13:10:00
6 dc:a6:32:21:59:2b 2020-07-13 13:15:00
```

What is going on?

Comment: the `x` within the function is being interpreted as the column `x` in `df`

Comment: @WalkerHarrison Any idea how to change that or why it works for one but not for the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests, the problem is that I have `function(x)` inside the `map` call and because `df` has an `x` column, things become weird. I chose another variable name for that, and now it's working.

```
la <- function(df, grp){
  gr <- df %>% pull({{grp}}) %>% unique()
  purrr::map(gr, function(tt){
    print(tt)
    filter(df, {{grp}} == tt)
  })
}
```